# How to serialize dates with JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: c#, datetime, javascriptserializer

I'm trying to use JavaScriptSerializer to store/retrieve a date. However, I'm not getting the same value back.

Here's is the test code

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var date = new DateTime(1997, 1, 27, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local);
var obj = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "theDate", date } };
var json = serializer.Serialize(obj);
var obj2 = serializer.DeserializeObject(json) as Dictionary<string, object>;
var date2 = (DateTime)obj2["theDate"];
var result = date == date2 ? "success" : "failure";
```

The date I get back is DateTimeKind.Utc instead of DateTimeKind.Local so the result is 'failure'. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"JavaScriptSerializer" Can't really be trusted for anything as complex as a date. I recommend picking your favourite date format and storing the date as a string. Or, for more precision, convert it to an epoch and store that number :)